# Get the Minimum and Maximum value within specific date range in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DataFrame that has the columns 'From' (datetime), 'To' (datetime). There are some overlapping in the ranges of different rows of the table.

Here is the simplified version of criteria dataframe (the date range is vary and overlapping with each other):

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'From': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-31',freq='2D'), 'To': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-05', end='2020-02-04',freq='2D')})

    From    To
0   2020-01-01  2020-01-05
1   2020-01-03  2020-01-07
2   2020-01-05  2020-01-09
3   2020-01-07  2020-01-11
4   2020-01-09  2020-01-13
5   2020-01-11  2020-01-15
6   2020-01-13  2020-01-17
7   2020-01-15  2020-01-19
8   2020-01-17  2020-01-21
9   2020-01-19  2020-01-23
10  2020-01-21  2020-01-25
11  2020-01-23  2020-01-27
12  2020-01-25  2020-01-29
13  2020-01-27  2020-01-31
14  2020-01-29  2020-02-02
15  2020-01-31  2020-02-04
```

And I have a dataframe which keep the daily high and low value like this

```
random.seed(0)
df2= pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-31'), 'High': [random.randint(7,15)+5 for i in range(31)], 'Low': [random.randint(0,7)-1 for i in range(31)]})

    Date    High    Low
0   2020-01-01  18  6
1   2020-01-02  18  6
2   2020-01-03  12  3
3   2020-01-04  16  -1
4   2020-01-05  20  -1
5   2020-01-06  19  0
6   2020-01-07  18  5
7   2020-01-08  16  -1
8   2020-01-09  19  6
9   2020-01-10  17  4
10  2020-01-11  15  2
11  2020-01-12  20  4
12  2020-01-13  14  0
13  2020-01-14  16  2
14  2020-01-15  14  2
15  2020-01-16  13  2
16  2020-01-17  16  1
17  2020-01-18  20  6
18  2020-01-19  14  0
19  2020-01-20  16  0
20  2020-01-21  13  4
21  2020-01-22  13  6
22  2020-01-23  17  0
23  2020-01-24  19  3
24  2020-01-25  20  3
25  2020-01-26  13  0
26  2020-01-27  17  4
27  2020-01-28  18  2
28  2020-01-29  17  3
29  2020-01-30  15  6
30  2020-01-31  20  0
```

Then I hope to get the maximum and minimum value based on the From Date and To Date in df1, Here is the expected result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'From': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-31',freq='2D'), 'To': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-05', end='2020-02-04',freq='2D'), 'High':[20,20,20,19,20,20,16,20,20,17,20,20,20,20,20,20], 'Low':[-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

    From    To  High    Low
0   2020-01-01  2020-01-05  20  -1
1   2020-01-03  2020-01-07  20  -1
2   2020-01-05  2020-01-09  20  -1
3   2020-01-07  2020-01-11  19  -1
4   2020-01-09  2020-01-13  20  0
5   2020-01-11  2020-01-15  20  0
6   2020-01-13  2020-01-17  16  1
7   2020-01-15  2020-01-19  20  0
8   2020-01-17  2020-01-21  20  0
9   2020-01-19  2020-01-23  17  0
10  2020-01-21  2020-01-25  20  0
11  2020-01-23  2020-01-27  20  0
12  2020-01-25  2020-01-29  20  0
13  2020-01-27  2020-01-31  20  0
14  2020-01-29  2020-02-02  20  0
15  2020-01-31  2020-02-04  20  0
```

I have tried to use resampling method, but it seems not support custom date range. I'm looking for a reasonably efficient and elegant way of doing this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume in your real case, the differences between `from` and `to` are not always an interval of 5 days, right? And also, what are the sizes of your two dataframes?

Comment: yes, the difference between "from" and "to" is not fixed. the size of df1 is about 4 millions rows. And the size of df2 is about 10000 rows. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the size of the data, I think you should consider another approach, the idea is to vectorize by chunk over df1 the comparison between dates with df2. It is lot more lines than other solutions, but it will be way faster for large dataframes.

```
# this is a parameter you can play with, 
# but if your df1 is in memory, this value should work
nb_split = int((len(df1)*len(df2))//4e6)+1

# work with arrays of flaot
arr1 = df1[['From','To']].astype('int64').to_numpy().astype(float)
arr2 = df2.astype('int64').to_numpy().astype(float)
# create result array
arr_out = np.zeros((len(arr1), 2), dtype=float)
i = 0 #index position
for arr1_sp in np.array_split(arr1, nb_split, axis=0):
    # get length of the chunk
    lft = len(arr1_sp)
    # get the min datetime in From and max in To
    min_from = arr1_sp[:, 0].min()
    max_to = arr1_sp[:, 1].max()

    # select the rows of arr2 tht are within the min and max date of the split
    arr2_sp = arr2[(arr2[:,0]>=min_from)&(arr2[:,0]<=max_to), :]

    # create an bool arraywith True when the date in arr2_sp is above from and below to
    # each row is the reuslt for each row of arr1_sp
    m = np.less_equal.outer(arr1_sp[:,0], arr2_sp[:, 0])\
        &np.greater_equal.outer(arr1_sp[:,1], arr2_sp[:, 0])

    # use this mask to get the values high and low within the range row-wise
    # and replace where the mask was False by np.nan
    arr_high = arr2_sp[:,1]*m
    arr_high[~m] = np.nan
    arr_low = arr2_sp[:,2]*m
    arr_low[~m] = np.nan

    # put the result in the result array
    arr_out[i:i+lft, 0] = np.nanmax(arr_high, axis=1)
    arr_out[i:i+lft, 1] = np.nanmin(arr_low, axis=1)
    i += lft #update first idx position for next loop

# create the columns in df1
df1['High'] = arr_out[:, 0]
df1['Low'] = arr_out[:, 1]
```

I tried with df1 with 10000 rows and df2 5000 rows, and this method is about 102ms while the method with apply `getHighLow2`is about 8s, so 80 time faster this way. Adn the results where the same.

Comment: Amazing, your method speeds up the whole process. I can finish the job within 1 minute. It is so cool. Thank you very much

Comment: @Seelfun I've been working on similar problem (df1 140K and df2 50K), but yeah 1min was what I expected for your data size. I'm sure you can even optimize it, but even if you run couple of times a day, not sure it worth it :)

Comment: I am a newbie in using python and numpy. I have not idea how to optimize it. but I believe this speed is really enough for the daily use. Anyany, thanks for your help gain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which does this:

- Checks the dates which are in the from/to interval
- Gets the maximum and minimum values of the `High` and `Low` columns respectively

```py
def get_high_low(d1):

    high = df2.loc[df2["Date"].isin(pd.date_range(d1["From"], d1["To"])), "High"].max()
    low = df2.loc[df2["Date"].isin(pd.date_range(d1["From"], d1["To"])), "Low"].max()

    return pd.Series([high, low], index=["High", "Low"])
```

Then we can just apply this function and concatenate the result with the dates.

```py
pd.concat([df1, df1.apply(get_high_low, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

The result

```py
    From    To  High    Low
0   2020-01-01  2020-01-05  19  4
1   2020-01-03  2020-01-07  17  5
2   2020-01-05  2020-01-09  19  5
3   2020-01-07  2020-01-11  19  2
4   2020-01-09  2020-01-13  17  4
5   2020-01-11  2020-01-15  19  4
6   2020-01-13  2020-01-17  19  5
7   2020-01-15  2020-01-19  18  5
8   2020-01-17  2020-01-21  18  0
9   2020-01-19  2020-01-23  19  3
10  2020-01-21  2020-01-25  19  5
11  2020-01-23  2020-01-27  19  5
12  2020-01-25  2020-01-29  17  5
13  2020-01-27  2020-01-31  17  3
14  2020-01-29  2020-02-02  17  1
15  2020-01-31  2020-02-04  13  -1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. isin a really good try. I havent thought about it. But I think the spending time is quite long if the dataset is very large. I need to test about its performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a cross merge and query, then groupby:

```
(df1.assign(dummy=1)
   .merge(df2.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy')   # this is cross merge
   .drop('dummy', axis=1)                    # remove the `dummy` column
   .query('From<=Date<=To')                  # only choose valid data
   .groupby(['From','To'])                   # groupby `From` and `To`
   .agg({'High':'max','Low':'min'})          # aggregation
   .reset_index()                            
)
```

Output:

```
         From         To  High  Low
0  2020-01-01 2020-01-05    20   -1
1  2020-01-03 2020-01-07    20   -1
2  2020-01-05 2020-01-09    20   -1
3  2020-01-07 2020-01-11    19   -1
4  2020-01-09 2020-01-13    20    0
5  2020-01-11 2020-01-15    20    0
6  2020-01-13 2020-01-17    16    0
7  2020-01-15 2020-01-19    20    0
8  2020-01-17 2020-01-21    20    0
9  2020-01-19 2020-01-23    17    0
10 2020-01-21 2020-01-25    20    0
11 2020-01-23 2020-01-27    20    0
12 2020-01-25 2020-01-29    20    0
13 2020-01-27 2020-01-31    20    0
14 2020-01-29 2020-02-02    20    0
15 2020-01-31 2020-02-04    20    0
```

Comment: Thank you. I can use it in small scale data. But when I use the code in full set data i.e.the size of df1 is about 4 million rows, and the size of df2 is about 8000 rows, the code cannot be executed.....

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple function that gets the min and max within a given date renge. Than use the apply function to add the columns.

```
def MaxMin(row):
    dfRange = df2[(df2['Date']>=row['From'])&(df2['Date']<=row['To'])] # df2 rows within a given date range
    row['High'] = dfRange['High'].max()
    row['Low'] = dfRange['Low'].min()
    return row

df1 = df1.apply(MaxMin, axis =1)
```

Comment: thank you, it seems okay, I am now testing the performance issue because the size of df1 is about 4 million rows, and the size of df2 is about 8000 rows. Hope it can finish the calculation around an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function:

```
def getHighLow(row):
    wrk = df2[df2.Date.between(row.From, row.To)]
    return pd.Series([wrk.High.max(), wrk.Low.min()], index=['High', 'Low'])
```

Then run:

```
df1.join(df1.apply(getHighLow, axis=1))
```

According to the DRY rule, it is better to find *wrk* (a set of rows between
given dates) **once** and then (form *wrk*) extract maximal *High* and
minimal *Low*.

Another advantage over the other solution: My code runs quicker by about
30 % (at least on my computer, measurements performed using *%timeit*).

## Edit

Yet quicker solution is when the search in *df2* can be performed **by index**
instead of "from regular column".

As a preparatory step run:

```
df2a = df2.set_index('Date')
```

Then define another variant of *getHighLow* function:

```
def getHighLow2(row):
    wrk = df2a.loc[row.From : row.To]
    return pd.Series([wrk.High.max(), wrk.Low.min()], index=['High', 'Low'])
```

To get the result, run:

```
df1.join(df1.apply(getHighLow2, axis=1))
```

For your data, the execution time is about a **half** of the other solution
(not including the time to create *df2a*, but it can be created just in this form (with *Date* as the index)).

Comment: yes, you are correct. my full set data df1 = 4 million row, df2 = 8000+ rows, the execution time of first code is about 150 min, the second code is about 75 mins, how is much faster than using the method of looping row one by one.